# Check internet connection from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check the Internet connection when an Excel workbook opens. For that, I'm trying the following code:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedState _
   Lib "wininet.dll" (ByRef dwflags As Long, _
   ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long

Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM As Long = &H1
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN As Long = &H2
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY As Long = &H4
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE As Long = &H20
Function IsInternetConnected() As Boolean
    Dim L As Long
    Dim R As Long
    R = InternetGetConnectedState(L, 0&)
    If R = 0 Then
        IsInternetConnected = False
    Else
        If R <= 4 Then
            IsInternetConnected = True
        Else
            IsInternetConnected = False
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

It works, but some users are reporting this is breaking Excel (it freezes Excel forever).

Is there a way to throw an error or somehow correct this code in order to find out what is the cause of the problem (Firewall, etc.)?

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: That's a 64-bit import. Are the 'freezing' computers running 32-bit Office installations? Do some research on compiler directives to see how to incorporate both into a single module declaration area.

Comment: @Jeeped thank you for your help. I'm running an a 32-bit Excel installation and I have no issues.

Comment: The `PtrSafe ` tells me that is a 64-bit import. Additionally, [InternetGetConnectedState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is intended to return a boolean, not a long.

Comment: Ok, so the 32-bit is compatible with the 64-bit environment and the problem should be somewhere else in the code, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the proper imports with compiler directives.

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Public Flg As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedState _
            Lib "wininet.dll" (lpdwFlags As LongPtr, _
            ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Boolean
#Else
    Public Flg As Long
    Public Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState _
            Lib "wininet.dll" (lpdwFlags As Long, _
            ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Boolean
#End If

Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM As Long = &H1
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN As Long = &H2
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY As Long = &H4
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE As Long = &H20

Function IsInternetConnected() As Boolean
    Dim R As Long

    R = InternetGetConnectedState(Flg, 0&)

    If Flg >= INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE Then
        Debug.Print "INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE"
    End If

    If CBool(R) Then
        IsInternetConnected = True
    Else
        IsInternetConnected = False
    End If
End Function

Sub main()
    Dim mssg As String
    If IsInternetConnected Then
        mssg = "Connected"
    Else
        mssg = "Not connected"
    End If
    MsgBox mssg
End Sub
```

I believe at least one of the problems was failing to provide the correct var-type to receive the `lpdwFlags`. I've added a public var within the compiler directives. The `Flg` var receives the flags from the function. These can be parsed bitwise against your constants to determine the state. See [InternetGetConnectedState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information (and a full set of flags).

This has been tested on both 32-bit and 64-bit xl2010.

Comment: Uau, thank you so much, I need to investigate further about InternetGetConnectedState and to test in other users' machines